# Popcorn-time.se ubuntu 14.04 lts black screen

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to run popcorn-time from the tar.gz I downloaded from popcorn-time.se site and when I extract and trying to run it by ./Popcorn-Time gives me an error of

> error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried the solution of

> sudo ln -sf /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0

and when I run it, it gives me this [splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXO8u.png) and after this a black screen with no options. The terminal is empty and the only thing I can do is kill the process.

I deleted the symlink and I downloaded the [libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/u/udev/libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb) as it was suggested in an other solution but the same result with the black screen.

Any ideas would be very helpful. Thank you in advance

Comment: same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve the problem; but there is none. Hopefully another version of Popcorntime is working fine! :)

Try to install from https://www.popcorntime.ws/download

1. Unpack and run from terminal ./Popcorn-Time